# How to add time range in formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have formula like this:

```
IF (Month(Today) - 12) < 1 THEN 
  (Month(Today)) 
ELSE
  (Month(Today) - 12)
```

How to add or insert to filter the time (syntax) range of the given month?

Comment: What do you mean by 'time range'?  Please cite an example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a time parameter and then write the filtering in `Record Selection Fromula`.

You can use Hour, Minute and Second functions available in crystal reports.

For e.g:

```
Hour(Current date time or current time)
```